# Shared Cross-Process Data Object

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need an object/class that keeps data synchronous over multiple processes. Like a singleton instance that works across processes. Is there already a built-in class that can handle this or what's the best way to implement such a thing (NSConnection, NSDistributedNotificationCenter, etc... ?)

Regards, Erik

Update:

---

Currently I have implemented such a thing using NSUserDefaults domains and syncing them to disc. But actually I prefer to avoid file system access, because it stresses the disc.

Comment: It depends on what kind of data you are trying to share and how often it does change. If `NSUserDefaults` works for you I’d not worry about the disk, I’d rather worry about the performance of my programs. So you probably should tell us more about your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filesystem will do that for you, or a database. Or you could even serve the shared data via Distributed Objects from a single server process.